# Triangle for a triangle

Tags: riddle, word, english

```
   1
  1 4
 1 3 3
5 2 2 2

1     salutation
1 4 5 a temptation
1 + 4 is archaic
3 & 4 algebraic
3 + 5 in chess
3 + 4 tasty? yes
2 + 5 removed after kill
2     a journey downhill
```

Summed for a triangle, what am I?

Comment: There's a difference between `3 & 4` and `3 + 4`?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes; they're different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I got it:

> ```
>     S
>    I E
>   R P I
>  N S K I
> ```

`1     salutation`

> SIR is a polite salutation

`1 4 5 a temptation`

> A SIREN can tempt you with their songs

`1 + 4 is archaic`

> SIRE is an archaic way of saying "sir"

`3 & 4 algebraic`

> PI and E appear in mathematics quite often, though not so much in algebra

`3 + 5 in chess`

> A PIN is a tactic in chess where you immobilize an opponent's piece by making it so that if your opponent moves it, a more valuable piece is left hanging

`3 + 4 tasty? yes`

> PIE is tasty (yum!)

`2 + 5 removed after kill`

> The SKIN of an animal is the first thing to be removed after a kill

`2     a journey downhill`

> To SKI is to journey downhill

Summed for a triangle, what am I?

> You are SIERPINSKI's triangle!

Comment: rot13(V znqr n zvfgnxr - CV naq R ner npghnyyl genafpraqragny, abg nytroenvp, ahzoref. Bu, jryy :()

Comment: Ah, nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is completely right, but I'll give it a go:

```
   S
  S M
 E S U
N I K S
```

*1     salutation*

> ???

*1 4 5 a temptation*

> This could be SIN, but it isn't quite fitting.

*1 + 4 is archaic*

> ???

*3 & 4 algebraic*

> SUM.

*3 + 5 in chess*

> ???

*3 + 4 tasty? yes*

> Similar to YUM?

*2 + 5 removed after kill*

> SKIN.

*2     a journey downhill*

> SKI.

Summed for a triangle, what am I?

> Around the edge of the triangle: MUSKINESS.

Comment: Alternatively, to better solve the first two clues, 4 could be `I` and 1 could be `SUP`. But then I don't know about archaic, algebraic, chess, or tasty.

Comment: ebg13(2 vf pbeerpg, ohg onpxjneqf - cebonoyl gung'yy uryc lbh fbyir gur erfg bs vg) Most everything else is way off, though.

Comment: @Avi Is my comment with an alternative approach also way off?

Comment: Yes, they're both incorrect.